# Sending relevant data by parameter or access with getter?

Tags: c#, parameters, getter

Especially in the case of events I was wondering if there's a good reason to choose one over the other?

C# example:

```
Class A
public event System.Action<someparam> someevent;

Class B
void eventcalledmethod(someparam param){
  //do something with param
}
```

Vs.

```
Class A
public event System.Action();
public static someparam Getter{get;}

Class B
void eventcalledmethod (){
  //do something with A.Getter
}
```

The second example is used in the Microsoft Windows C++ API for the handling of window events.

Comment: You should really be using https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this as this is not really a question for its not working here is what I have tried.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint, didn't know where I was when posting this

Answer (score 0):

Answering as I'd argue that this is not a matter of style, as the first method provides different functionality to the second (ignoring doing silly things that you wouldn't normally do anywhere else in your code base).

The first method has the benefit of being able to pass information about a specific instance of A (or any other information required for the event). This is idiomatic and follows normal OOP practices regarding polymorphism and encapsulation. In terms of patterns, it allows for dependency injection amongst other things.

The second method ties the event handling to a static property of A, meaning each instance of A cannot have it's own values for that. It's also not idiomatic, in that most programmers expect the event to contain all information needed for handling the event - tying the handling to a static property adds unnecessary coupling.

I know this might seem like a style argument, but I'd really argue the first is simply more flexible and as such should be preferred where possible.

Comment: Thanks @Bilkokuya for your detailed answer. The second example wasn't explicitly ment for instance information. I remember Unity's Input class providing every important information statically. If there was an event for let's say OnMouseClicked, there would be no need for the event to pass the mouse button clicked because one could access some Input classes struct for that information. Maybe another question makes this clearer: "if I wanted to know if a specific object did something, do I register to it's according event, or do I register to a class event passing it"?

Comment: @AlexanderSeeck Thanks for the clarification.

The important thing to me is that the event contains all the information needed about the event and who sent it. Whether that's from a static instance or from each object themselves - if you don't pass the source object into the event, you need a separate handler for each object's event.

Ideally, if you register to an object's event, it should still send a reference of itself in the event.

Outside of having that information, what actually sends the event is completely stylistic and will have no real impact on what you can/can't achieve.